# Cannot access cloud SQL from firebase cloud functions in a different project

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have two GCP projects(one of them is a firebase project), and I am trying access a cloud SQL instance on one project from the other project's firebase cloud functions.

I have followed the instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions

On this instruction, it says

> When connecting resources in two different projects, make sure that
>   both projects have enabled the correct IAM roles and have given the
>   service account the correct permissions.

and I am not entirely sure if I'm doing this part correct. What I did was to copy the service account email address from my cloud function project that looks like this: "service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" and copied that into my other GCP project's IAM page and gave it a CloudSQL Client role.

This is the code that I am using to access the database:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as mysql from "mysql";

export const sql = functions
  .https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const query = "select * from my_table limit 1;";
      const pool: mysql.Pool = mysql.createPool({
        socketPath: functions.config().cloud_sql.socket_path,
        user: functions.config().cloud_sql.user,
        password: functions.config().cloud_sql.password,
        database: functions.config().cloud_sql.database,
        connectionLimit: 5,
        timezone: "+0900"
      });

      pool.query(query, [], (err: mysql.MysqlError | null, results: any) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

When I access this function, I get this error in the console:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

What could I be missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I just solved it shortly after I post this question lol.

I was giving wrong service account the IAM role. Instead of adding Cloud SQL Client role to "service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" account like it says in the official documentation(https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions), you need to add Cloud SQL Client role to App Engine default service account, which ends with something like this "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"

Answer (score 1):

The project default service account that cloud function uses **during function execution**, (Runtime service account) is `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity):

> During function execution, Cloud Functions uses the service account
>   PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com as its identity.
>
> By default, the runtime service account has the Editor role, which
>   lets it access many GCP services.
>
> If you have multiple functions all accessing different resources,
>   you'll likely want to give each function its own identity. This can be
>   done by deploying the function with a named service account that has
>   the correct role. The service account being deployed must have been
>   created in the same project as the function it is attached to.

Also :

> At runtime, Cloud Functions defaults to using the App Engine default
>   service account (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com), which has
>   the Editor role on the project. You can change the roles of this
>   service account to limit or extend the permissions for your running
>   functions. You can also change which service account is used by
>   providing a non-default service account on a per-function basis.

You mentioned this link [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions):

> Cloud Functions uses a service account to authorize your connections
>   to Cloud SQL. This service account must have the correct IAM
>   permissions to successfully connect. Unless otherwise configured, the
>   default service account is in the format
>   service-YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

This service account is used only for **administrative actions** [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam):

> For administrative actions on your project during the creation,
>   updating, or deletion of functions, the Cloud Functions service uses
>   the Google Cloud Functions service agent service account
>   (service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com).
>
> By default, this service account has the cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
>   role on your project. Creating, updating, and deleting functions may
>   fail if you change this account's permissions.

I would suggest to deploy the cloud function with it's own service account:

1. Create services accounts:

   ```
    gcloud iam service-accounts create function-one --display-name function-one
   ```
2. Assign the necessary roles to the services account:

   ```
    gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my_project --member serviceAccount:function-one@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/cloudsql.client
   ```
3. Deploy the function with the service account:

   ```
    gcloud beta functions deploy ... --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
   ```

SERVICE_ACCOUNT

> The email address of the IAM service account associated with the
>   function at runtime. The service account represents the identity of
>   the running function, and determines what permissions the function
>   has. If not provided, the function will use the project's default
>   service account.

I understand form the documentation that both services account should have the necessary roles to connect to Cloud SQL from a different project:

```
   PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
   YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: In your step 3, what is `SERVICE_ACCOUNT`, in relation to commands [1] and [2]? Is that `function-one`, ie ` gcloud beta functions deploy --service-account=function-one`?

Comment: yes, is the service account created on step 1, run gcloud iam service-accounts list and you will see the full name